# Still showing nil variable on didSelectRow method

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode6, didselectrowatindexpath

courseData is an array of struct objects. Each object has 9 string variables (holeNumber, Par, SI, plan etc) The cells populate fine but when you click on a row I am trying to get a detail view controller to populate an image view with the image held under variable plan for the relevant struct in the array. Complete code shown. courseImage1 variable still shows nil.  Please help I have been stuck for 3-days!

Note: var CourseImage1: UIImage? is declared publicly at the top of my code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return courseData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Hole") as UITableViewCell

    let item = courseData[indexPath.row]

    let holeLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel
    holeLabel.text = item.holeNumber

    let parLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as UILabel
    parLabel.text = item.par

    let siLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as UILabel
    siLabel.text = item.SI

    let wyLabel = cell.viewWithTag(4) as UILabel
    wyLabel.text = item.whiteYards

    let yyLabel = cell.viewWithTag(5) as UILabel
    yyLabel.text = item.yellowYards

    let ryLabel = cell.viewWithTag(6) as UILabel
    ryLabel.text = item.redYards

    let photo = item.image
    let placeholder = cell.viewWithTag(7) as UIImageView
    placeholder.image = UIImage(named: photo)


    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let courseSection = courseData[indexPath.row]

    var tipPic = courseSection.plan
    var courseImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: tipPic)!
    courseImage1 = courseImage

}

     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var destViewController : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
        if (segue.identifier == "courseTip") {

        destViewController.receivedPic = courseImage1

    }
    }
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    (indexPath, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: I think you have a tiny typo in your did**S**electRowAtIndexPath method - the 's' should be capitalised.

Comment: Thanks.  Now populating my image view but strangely with random images from the array rather than the one relating to the index path row?

Comment: I forgot - didSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called AFTER prepareForSegue - so you may be getting the image for the last but one cell clicked.

Comment: Move the code that sets the image to prepareForSegue - you will need to use indexPathForSelectedRow to determine which row was clicked.

Comment: cell last clicked is exactly what is happening! how do i implement indexPathForSelectedRow into the prepare for segue method?

Comment: It's a bit too long for a comment, I'll add an answer...

Comment: That would be fantastic, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because didSelectRowAtIndexPath fires after the prepareForSegue, put all the relevant logic in the latter method:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destViewController : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
    if (segue.identifier == "courseTip") {
        // I assume "self.tableView" points to your TV, if not amend the name below
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let courseSection = courseData[indexPath.row]
            var tipPic = courseSection.plan
            var courseImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: tipPic)!
            destViewController.receivedPic = courseImage
        } else {
            println("Oops, no row has been selected")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem - grateful if you could "accept" the answer (though entirely optional).